# How can I make it so a JLabel only displays the first line of text?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

This is a JLabel with a height that is not allowed to vary. However when there is too much text to fit in its given size it attempts to display both lines. I do not want this, how do I make it so that only the first line up to the "in new" is displayed?

Comment: To my knowledge making a JLabel with mutliple lines is only possible with  html... Are you sure you mean a [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)? If yes, I don't get the question, you just have to do it without html then.

Comment: Count up to the number of characters you want to display.  Set the JLabel text to a substring of the input text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to not use html (ie, `"<html>"` inside of the string) for it was what was causing the lines to warp when too long. All bolding and monospacing had to be done without using html.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it `scrollable`? This way you can maintain the preferred size, and at the same time display the info when it's needed. You just have to put the JLabel inside a JScrollPane:

```
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(yourJLabel,
                                       JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLABAR_AS_NEEDED,
                                       JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLABAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Comment: `..._SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` is the default for a JScrollPane. No need to add those parameters. Also this would NOT work because the OP says the label is a fixed height. If the scrollbar would appear then you would not be able to see the text. So if anything you would need to make the horizontal scrollbar always visible, but then is this case the component will take up twice the space it currently does.